# New blog post shows immediately in google search results where as other HTML content takes time, why?

Tags: google-search, google-ranking

I have a blog which has been active for 3 years. Recently I posted an article and it immediately appeared in google search. Maybe 5 to 10 minutes.

A point to note is I was logged into my google account. Maybe google checked my post's when I searched since I am logged in?

Yet I logged out and used another browser and searched again with that specific text and it appeared in google search result.

How did this happen?

However, if I make an article in static HTML and publish, it takes time. (I assume this is the case but I haven't tested much). Yet tested a few cases after updating it in my sitemap xml.

How does google search work for a blog and other content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Were your personal search results turned off? When was the page cached? It's likely your blog pinged Google along with other search engines once you published the post. Well Google blog search at least which is different than Google Bot.

Search results work just the same for a blog post page compared to any other content page. Google has been crawling, indexing, and caching pages much quicker than in the last few years. Where in the past they would push updates to their data centers lets say once per week now it's probably a few times a day if not instantaneous.

The blog post when generated may have gotten naturally more internal links than some of your other pages. It's content is certainly fresher than other pages on your site most likely and the HTTP response from that page told Google the content was very recently updated.

All in all what you're asking is "How does Google work" and there's no answer that can tell you exactly how they indexed that one blog post as quick as they did. Maybe it was luck that they were crawling your site when you posted and it coincided with an update to their index.

Comment: yes. i assume the same like your last point. besides blogs ping google when new post is made. these two have more possibility.

Comment: for seo fresh content or content which is old and well used? i had been thinking content by age gets more importance yet there are other factors i should also consider for fresh content getting indexed... just asking..

Comment: You asked `How does google search work for a blog and other content?` no one knows and people will only speculate on how Google search works. So the bottom line is this. Write new content as often as you can. Make it unique and write for people not search engines and you'll keep Google happy.

Comment: haha... thats a punch. yes... ofcourse writing for people... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would do well to monitor your server logs for access patterns, what URLs the Googlebot is retrieving, what status codes it is getting in response, and verify that the URLs to the static HTML files you speak of are actually correct in your sitemap.